# Pass a javascript variable to html. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable in Javascript:

```
var test ="whatever"
```

I just want to pass this variable inside a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" class="myinput" value="">
```

I tried:

```
$('.myinput').attr('test');
```

But it does not seem to work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did it help, if so please mark it is as accepted for closure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Use [**`.val`**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function to set the value of hidden input.
2. Remove the quotes to consider it as a variable and not a string literal.

See below code:

```
$('.myinput').val(test);
```

Comment: *"Use `.val` function to set the value of the textbox"* More to the point, to set the value of a `hidden` `input`. (Hidden inputs are not text boxes.)